# How to improve the search efficiency of SQLite database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I have a sqlite database for saving some map data cached from the internet.
I choose sqlite because it's **portable** and **serverless**.
For each map tile, it contains the following information:

```
x, y, zoom, type, image
```

So my table has them as the 5 columns.
I use the call

```
SELECT image WHERE x = ... AND y=... AND zoom=... AND type =...
```

However, as the database becomes larger (more than 15000 rows), the query speed becomes very slow (>1 seconds on average).

How could I make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use indexes to improve performance.  For this condition:

```
WHERE x = ... AND y=... AND zoom=... AND type =...
```

The best index is `table(x, y, zoom, type)`.  Because the conditions are all equality conditions, the order of the columns in the index does not matter.

Comment: Hi, my understanding to your kind suggestions is:
(1) create two tables (id, x, y, zoom, type) and (id_2, image)
(2) select id where x=... and y=... and zoom=... and type = ...
(3) select image where id_2 = id.
Is my understanding correct, sorry I am new to database.

Comment: @Nyaruko No. Create an index (using [CREATE INDEX](http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)) on table `image` over columns `x`, `y`, `zoom` and `type`.